# probability choosing letters

Tags: probability

Suppose we choose an n letter word at random (uniformly) from $\Sigma^n\;$where $\; \Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$. What is the probability that the letters of the word are in (increasing) alphabetical order?

So from sum of events / sum of all possible events:

I believe the answer is $\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!.3^n}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Consider the factorial again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got a mistake. (I did it too at first attempt). For $n=2$ your formula gives $0$. Which is obviously not correct!

The probability is (number of ordered words)/(number of words).

Number of words is $3^n$ - this is easy.
Difficult part is to calculate the number of ordered words.

Let's take an ordered word. Let's put a '|' character after all the 'a' letters. Then we put a '|' after all the 'b' letters. Positions of these two '|' characters in $n+2$-letter word define define the original ordered word: '|' characters split the range into 3 parts (some of them may be empty) and we fill the parts with 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

So we need to calculate the number of possibilities to put 2 '|' characters into $n+2$ positions. Which is ${n+2 \choose 2}$.

And the final answer would be ${n+2 \choose 2}/3^n$.

Comment: I get it now! Thank you very much!